# Best way to remove duplicate characters (words) in a string?

Tags: python, string, duplicates

What would be the best way of removing any duplicate characters and sets of characters separated by spaces in string?

I think this example explains it better:

```
foo = 'h k k h2 h'
```

should become:

```
foo = 'h k h2' # order not important
```

Other example:

```
foo = 's s k'
```

becomes:

```
foo = 's k'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
' '.join(set(foo.split()))
```

Note that split() by default will split on all whitespace characters.  (e.g. tabs, newlines, spaces)

So if you want to split ONLY on a space then you have to use:

```
' '.join(set(foo.split(' ')))
```

Comment: ' '.join(set(foo.split())) is more pythonic these days.  Also, you're missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean?

```
' '.join( set( someString.split() ) )
```

That's the unique space-delimited words in no particular order.

Comment: And ' '.join(set(someString.split())) puts it back together again

Comment: @Ali A: 30 years of coding.  20+ years before PEP 8.  Can't teach an old fart new trix.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Quite the change from what I had.

Comment: @Amything: hard for us to help with new concepts when you don't post your code.

Comment: S.Lott: blimey, you sound even older than me!

Comment: @Ali A: I am old -- my first programming was on an IBM 1620 -- discrete logic, core memory, special room cooling, punched cards, etc., etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
out = []
for word in input.split():
    if not word in out:
        out.append(word)
output_string = " ".join(out)
```

Longer than using a set, but it keeps the order.

**Edit:** Nevermind.  I missed the part in the question about order not being important.  Using a set is better.

Comment: +1, when order is important, your solution is good. Can you give better version which will optimize the searching as well.