# Fastest way to deduplicate contiguous characters in string - Python

Tags: python, string, unicode, duplicates

We can deduplicate the contiguous characters in a string with:

```
def deduplicate(string, char):
    return char.join([substring for substring in string.strip().split(char) if substring])
```

E.g.

```
>>> s = 'this is   an   irritating string with  random spacing  .'
>>> deduplicate(s)
'this is an irritating string with random spacing .'
```

On the command line there is a `squeeze` option for `tr`:

```
$ tr -s " " < file
```

**Is there a `squeeze` function in Python's string?**

**What is the fastest way to deduplicate contiguous characters in string in Python?**

Please note that the character to be deduplicated should be any ascii/unicode character and not just `\s` / whitespace. (It's fine to have 2 sub-answers for ascii and unicode.

Comment: Is the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18799050/5359243) similar to the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: Is it faster than the list comprehension?

Comment: doesn't [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799036/python-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-character-from-string/18799050#18799050) code just squeeze everything? doesn't @alvas want to be able to specify which character to squeeze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `deduplicate` function is actually really fast. But there can be some improvements made to make it even faster.  I have `lambda`ized your function and called it `org_deduplicate` (below). Now for some time tests (using iPython's `%timeit`):

```
s = 'this is   an   irritating string with  random spacing  .'

org_deduplicate = lambda s,c: c.join([substring for substring in s.strip().split(c) if substring])

%timeit org_deduplicate(s,' ')
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.59 µs per loop
```

but the `strip` really isn't necessary and may even give you unexpected results (if you are not deduplicating whitespace) so we can try:

```
org_deduplicate2 = lambda s,c: c.join(substring for substring in s.split(c) if substring)

%timeit org_deduplicate2(s,' ')
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.4 µs per loop
```

which speeds things up by a tiny bit but its not all that impressive. Lets try a different approach... regular expressions. These are also nice because they give you the flexibility to choose any regular expression as your "character" to deduplicate (not just a single char):

```
import re

re_deduplicate = lambda s,c: re.sub(r'(%s)(?:\1)+' %c, '\g<1>',  s)
re_deduplicate2 = lambda s,c: c.join(re.split('%s+'%c,s))

%timeit re_deduplicate(s,' ')
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.8 µs per loop

%timeit re_deduplicate2(s,' ')
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.47 µs per loop
```

The second one is faster but neither are even close to your original function. It looks like regular string operations are quicker than `re` functions. What if we try zipping instead (use `itertools.izip` if working with Python 2):

```
zip_deduplicate = lambda s,c: ''.join(s1 for s1,s2 in zip(s,s[1:]) if s1!=c or s1!=s2)

%timeit zip_deduplicate(s,' ')
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.9 µs per loop
```

Still no improvement. The zip method makes too many substrings which makes doing `''.join` slow. Ok one more try... what about `str.replace` called recursively:

```
def rec_deduplicate(s,c):                                                                             
    if s.find(c*2) != -1:   
        return rec_deduplicate(s.replace(c*2, c),c)
    return s

%timeit rec_deduplicate(s,' ')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.83 µs per loop
```

Not bad, that seems to be our winner. But just to be sure, lets try it against our original function with a really long input string:

```
s2 = s*100000

%timeit rec_deduplicate(s2,' ')
10 loops, best of 3: 64.6 ms per loop

%timeit org_deduplicate(s2,' ')
1 loop, best of 3: 209 ms per loop
```

Yup, it looks like it scales nicely. But lets try one more test, the recursive deduplicator only removes duplicate chars of length 2 each time it is called. So does it still do better with long duplicate chars:

```
s3 = 'this is                       an                        irritating string with                                  random spacing  .'

%timeit rec_deduplicate(s3,' ')
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.93 µs per loop

%timeit org_deduplicate(s3,' ')
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.99 µs per loop
```

It does lose some of its advantage when there are long strings of repeated characters to remove.

In summary, use your original function (with a few tweaks maybe) if your strings will have long substrings of repeating characters. Otherwise, the recursive version is fastest.

Comment: Great answer @bunji !! Thanks for the insights!

Comment: Please note for anyone who bumps into this (it has more Google juice than the one it is marked as duplicating), the original and its variant in this answer will trim instances of "c" that exist at the beginning/end of a string. This is probably desired behavior for spaces, but might not be for non-space characters.

Answer (score 3):

Itertools are a good lib to try

```
>>> t = "THHHISSS ISSS BBBBSSSSS"
>>> import itertools
>>> ''.join(char for char, _ in itertools.groupby(t))
'THIS IS BS'
```

Comment: Whoops did not see @FeebleOldMan answer/link

Comment: doesn't this just squeeze everything? don't you want to be able to specify which character to squeeze?