# Replace consecutive repeated characters with one - Column-wise operation - `pandas.DataFrame`

Tags: python, pandas

How do I remove repeated characters in string and just leave one of them.

e.g:-

```
"Bertuggggg Mete"
```

to

```
"Bertug Mete"
```

I've just read data like this:

```
dataFrame = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Bertug\\Desktop\\example.xlsx")
```

Name
0 Bertuggggg Mete

Input is read from .xlsx file. I have tried split and strip functions but they don't work seem to work as expected.

How I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Have look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799036/python-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-character-from-string

Comment: Check this post and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841303/removing-duplicate-characters-from-a-string

Comment: I've looked that but it contains just two characters. My question is for more than two

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Best Way to remove duplicate character from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799036/python-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-character-from-string)

Comment: @Bertug, you can use idea from  stackoverflow.com/questions/18799036/ . Also, from  stackoverflow.com/questions/9841303 : If you look at the regex in the solution, you will get the answer. Hint: You need to use `\1` instead of `\1\1`

Answer (score 4):

Check this out:

Replace `column_name` with whatever is the column name you want to apply the replacement.

```
min_threshold_rep = 2
column_name = 'Name'
dataframe[column_name]= dataframe[column_name].str.replace(r'(\w)\1{%d,}'%(min_threshold_rep-1), r'\1')
```

NOTE: this would replace every `min_threshold_rep` number of consecutive character with one character.

Comment: It is working thank you so much. Can you explain in here  (r'(\w)\1*', r'\1'). How did you solve this :)

Comment: `\1` represents the first found group in the string here-`(\w)` which replaces multiple consecutive instances into one.

Comment: Just go to the official docs : https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Answer (score 0):

python code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = 'Bertuggggg Mete'
    if len(s) == 0:
        print('wrong!')
        exit()
    r = s[0]
    for c in s:
        if r[len(r) - 1] != c:
            r += c
    print(r)
```

java code :

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Bertuggggg Mete";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0, j = s.length(); i < j; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            sb.append(s.charAt(0));
        }
        if (s.charAt(i) != sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1)) {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}

}
```

Comment: you just gave java solution to a Python problem :P

Comment: So, I think. Now you can move this code somewhere in gist for your future reference and delete from here :P

Comment: with python 3.5 ?