# Remove duplicated letters from pandas column exist only to each other, Python

Tags: python, pandas

from this question : [Python: Best Way to remove duplicate character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799036/python-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-character-from-string/18799050?noredirect=1#comment100031593_18799050) 
answer:

```
''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby(string_to_remove)
```

I know how to remove duplicated letters exists only next to each other, how to apply this solution to column in pandas?

df:

`df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['ODOODY','LLHHEELLO'],'B':['NNMminee','DDasdss']})`

expected result:

```
A,B
ODODY,NMine
LHELO,Dasds
```

tried:
`df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby(x['A'])))`
thanks !

Comment: Nice requirements. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), if necessary filter columns for remove duplicates:

```
import itertools
cols = ['A','B']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: ''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby(x)))
#for all columns
#df = df.applymap(lambda x: ''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby(x)))
print (df)
       A       B
0  ODODY  NMmine
1  LHELO   Dasds
```

Solution with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is possible, but need process each value separately, so aded list comprehension:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: [''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby(y)) for y in x])
print (df)
       A       B
0  ODODY  NMmine
1  LHELO   Dasds
```

Or use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
f = lambda x: ''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby(x))
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(f)
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(f)
```

Comment: right! i have tried same way but i did mistake at the and of the groupby , because i have tried, ...groupby(x.[col]) not only x.
Also there is mistake, please change applymap to apply, and will be good for me , thanks!