# How to return a list of items in a string while preserving the original order of elements in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, function

I am stuck on this coding challenge from Codewars:

"Implement the function unique_in_order which takes as argument a sequence and returns a list of items without any elements with the same value next to each other and preserving the original order of elements."

"For example:

```
unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
unique_in_order('ABBCcAD')         == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'c', 'A', 'D']
unique_in_order([1,2,2,3,3])       == [1,2,3]
```

"

This is how far I was able to come so far:

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    iterable= list(set(iterable))

    return sorted(iterable)
```

Which gets me an output of:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

For the following input:

```
['AAAABBBCCDAABBB']
```

instead of the desired output of:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: `set()` returns unique items in the given list

Comment: @ElSheikh, it won't save order

Comment: [Ordered Set](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/) preserves order

Comment: using set is not what you need to do here, the function doesn't want the unique elements, it basically wants `[k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(iterable)]`

Comment: @OlvinRoght I know, I am just informing him/her with what `set()` does

Answer (score 2):

`set` creates an object with each element in the list occuring only once. Instead of a built in function you're going to have to write something yourself. How to do this?

First, create the input and a list that willstore your result:

```
input_word = 'aabbbaaa'
output_list = []
```

Now, what we will do is loop over the word, and every new letter we append. So we need to track what the "current" letter is:

```
current_letter = None
```

At first we set it to None because we have no current letter yet. Now we loop over the word:

```
for letter in input_word:
    if letter != current_letter:
        output_list.append(letter)
        current_letter = letter
print(output_list)
>>> ['a', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to do this:

```
>>> string = "AAAABBBCCDAABBB"
>>> new_list = []
>>> for i in string:
...     if not new_list:
...             new_list.append(i)
...     elif new_list[-1] != i:
...             new_list.append(i)
...
>>> new_list
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

You can wrap this into a function if need be.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a list comprehension using `zip` and some nifty slicing. It's basically the pairwise recipe without using itertools. If you want you can look that recipe up if you need it too.

```
[it[0]] + [nc for c, nc in zip(it, it[1:]) if c != nc]
```

For clarity `c` is the current character `nc` is the next character in the pair.

---

```
>>> it = 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'
>>> [it[0]] + [nc for c, nc in zip(it, it[1:]) if c != nc]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

---

This can be shown as a standard for loop as well for more clarity:

```
result = [it[0]]
for c, nc in zip(iterable, iterable[1:]):
    if c != nc:
        result.append(nc)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    output = []
    letter = None
    for current in iterable:
        if current != letter:
            output.append(current)
            letter = current

    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Iterate through the string. Whenever *ith* element and *ith+1* don't match add the *ith* element to list `res.

```
def unique_order(_iter):
    if not _iter:
        return []
    res=[]
    for i in range(0,len(_iter)-1):
        if _iter[i]!=_iter[i+1]:
            res.append(_iter[i])
    res.append(_iter[-1])
    return res

unique_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') #output is ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

---

[`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can be used here.

```
from itertools import groupby
def unique_order(_iter):
    return [k for k, g in groupby(_iter)] #'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'--> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `itertools.groupby`. The behaviour you want is the same as the `uniq` command. As the [doc](https://devdocs.io/python~3.8/library/itertools#itertools.groupby) says, `groupby` has a similar beahviour.

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> [k for k, _ in itertools.groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
>>>
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799036/python-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-character-from-string) describes a similar behaviour to yours.