# How remove duplicate letters in a string

Tags: python

Is there a way to remove duplicate characters? For example if we input "hello", the output will be "helo"; another example is "overflow", the output would be "overflw"; another example "paragraphs", the output would be "parghs".

I have tried

```
def removeDupes(mystring):
    newStr = ""
    for ch in string:
        if ch not in newStr:
            newStr = newStr + ch
    return newStr
```

Comment: So what is the problem with that code? — By the way, the argument is called `mystring`, but you use `string` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `string` to `mystring`:

```
def removeDupes(mystring):
    newStr = ""
    for ch in mystring:
        if ch not in newStr:
            newStr = newStr + ch
    return newStr

print removeDupes("hello")
print removeDupes("overflow")
print removeDupes("paragraphs")

>>> 
helo
overflw
parghs
```

Answer (score 1):

yes with something called a set:

```
unique = set()

[ unique.add(c) for c in 'stringstring' ]
```

Comment: This wouldn't preserve order, if that's important to the OP

Comment: also, wouldn't just `set(x for x in 'stringstring')` be better and more Pythonic?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `collections.OrderedDict` for this:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> data = "paragraphs"
>>> print "".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data))
parghs
```

Comment: -1 for plagiarizing [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9841328/1223693)

Comment: @Doorkob I wasn't aware of that answer - it's just the way I would do it.

Comment: okay, I'll just assume good faith here and believe you. anyway, it's a duplicate question

Comment: You're right, it is. Flagged it!