# "index" attribute - Python

Tags: python, indexing

When I was reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9841401/5175044 to a question on removing duplicates from a string, I couldn't understand what the `index` attribute meant in

```
''.join(sorted(set(foo), key=foo.index))
```

I did this example run:

```
foo = "Wicked long string"
>>> "".join(sorted(set(foo),key = foo.index))
'Wicked longstr'
>>> "".join(sorted(set(foo)))
' Wcdegiklnorst'
```

which leads me to think that it helps in keeping the order of the characters.

Comment: Okay... so what is your question?

Comment: All sequences support the `.index` method, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Comment: This sorts a `set` (which is unordered) using the original lists index. So you get the same order as the original list. Without `key` it would just sort the characters lexically.

Comment: @CoryKramer, I don't get what `.index` is, because it has nothing to do with `.index(sub[, start[, end]])`, does it?

Comment: @AChampion, so if I run `>>> for i in foo: print i.index` it returns every list element's original index?

Comment: you are sorting by the  position of the character  in the original string, on a sidenote it is a pretty inefficient way to do so for large strings. Using a dict to store the index and passing dict.get as the key would be better.

Comment: what you want to be reading is this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting the part about Key Functions

Comment: so if you understand what the key parameter does you can look at what the .index does...

Comment: @tulians not quite the equivalent would be `>>> for i in foo: print foo.index(i)`. The `key` parameter is a function that is passed every element being sorted with the result being used to order the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others Pythons `sorted()` function and  the `sort()` method of a list provides the `key` parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element prior to making comparisons.

The key thing is that this `key` parameter is a function object that takes when it is called only *one* argument and returns exactly *one* value which is used for the sorting.

A anonymous ["lambda" function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) is often used for this purpose, since its definition does not include a `return` statement and therefor always contains an one expression which is returned.

For instance

```
>>> myKey = lambda e: id(e)
```

creates an *(anonymous) function object*

```
>>> type(myKey)
<class 'function'>
```

which takes one argument and returns a value and would therefore be a valid `key` for sorting.

If you want to call the `myKey` function  object now you would simply do this:

```
>>> myKey(42)
503732608
```

---

To solve your problem you could create a lambda function as `key` which takes an element and returns its index in the `foo` string to keep the order of the characters:

```
>>> foo = "Wicked long string"
>>> "".join(sorted(set(foo), key = lambda e: foo.index(e)))
'Wicked longstr'
```

On the other hand -- since `foo.index` is a function object itself which takes one argument and returns one value -- you could pass this object instead to the `sorted()` function and by-pass the lambda definition:

```
>>> "".join(sorted(set(foo),key = foo.index))
'Wicked longstr'
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`index` is a method used for most ordered sequences to find the first occurrence of some element in that sequence.  For example `"My string is here.".index(" ")` would return `2` because the first occurrence of `" "` is at position `2`.  It is used for strings, tuples, lists, etc.  The documentation on [sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) has more about it.

Comment: I understand the use of index when it has parameters. What I don't seem to understand is when it's used as an attribute.

Comment: Methods are not special attributes just because they are methods; they are attributes that can be moved around and referenced just like anything else.  The `sorted` function has its own way of sorting, but you can also specify a key.  This key is a function which, when given a value, returns a certain number that `sorted` will use to put that value in its list.  In this case, The value of each element is its index in `foo`.  That way all equal elements will have the same sort value, and will therefore be sorted next to each other.

Comment: @tulians the attribute is just a variable that stores a reference to that function that you can use like anything else. Try this: `x = 'hello'.index` then call like `x('o')`, `x('e')`, `x('y')`.