# Remove duplicated chars in column

Tags: python, string, pandas, duplicates

I have a DataFrame with the following info

```
countries    flags
FR           aabb
DE           abc
UK           bbcc
IT           ddd
```

I want to transform the flags column into a new column that contains only the non-duplicated charts of the flags column. The result should be

```
countries    flags
FR           ab
DE           abc
UK           bc
IT           d
```

Comment: Consecutive duplicates or *all* duplicates? ie... does `aba` stay `aba` or become `ab` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841303/removing-duplicate-characters-from-a-string

Comment: @Jon Clements All duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with `set` which remove duplicates, sort them by `sorted` and last `join` to `string`:

```
df.flags = df.flags.apply(lambda x: "".join(sorted(set(x))))
print (df)
  countries flags
0        FR    ab
1        DE   abc
2        UK    bc
3        IT     d
```