# Remove repeated letters in Python

Tags: python, string

How do i remove repeated letters in a string?

**Tried this without success..**

```
def shorten_string(char_str):
    new=''
    for i in range(0,len(char_str)-1):
       if char_str[i-1] != char_str[i]:
           new += char_str[i]
return new
```

EDIT: Misunderstanding: i do not want to delete all repeated characthers. Just if they are repeated in order.

```
input: lloolleellaa
outpu: lolela
```

Comment: can you add sample output and input.

Comment: @harshil9968 Check the first line of the post.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9841401/3832970

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing adjacent equal items can be done as follows with `groupby`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ''.join(c[0] for c in itertools.groupby('haalllooo'))
'halo'
```

This simply takes the heads of each of the groups of equal items.

```
>>> ''.join(c[0] for c in itertools.groupby('haalllooo thheeerrree tttthhhiiisss iiisss aaann eeeexxxaaammpppllleee'))
'halo there this is an example'
```

To keep only the unique items in order:

```
def unique(it):
    s = set()
    for x in it:
        if x not in s:
           s.add(x)
           yield x
```

This can be used like this:

```
>>> ''.join(unique('haalllooo'))
'halo'
>>> ''.join(unique('haalllooo thheeerrree tttthhhiiisss iiisss aaann eeeexxxaaammpppllleee'))
'halo terisnxmp'
```

Comment: You should consider adding this as an answer to the duplicate.  A solution which only removes adjacent items isn't represented on that question yet.

Answer (score 8):

It is the same logic as is for all languages. This is a frequent question asked in interviews. Basically you assign each character of the string to a data structure. The choice of the data structure differs from language and performance. Sometimes they might also ask if the order matters or not.

```
>>> foo = 'haalllooo'
>>> ''.join(sorted(set(foo), key=foo.index))
'halo'
```

Comment: See edit, I wrote the question in a bad way i guess.

Comment: @SanderB Then the solution by Dan D. does what you need.

Comment: I upvoted this before I realized that it actually has a major bug that deletes **all** duplicated letters, not just the ones that are next to each other.  By the time I realized the error, it was too late to take the upvote back.  Beware this answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It worked for me too in the Roman Urdu case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My solution with regex:

```
>>> import re

>>> re.compile(r'(.)\1{1,}', re.IGNORECASE).sub(r'\1', "haalllooo thheeerrree tttthhhiiisss iiisss aaann eeeexxxaaammpppllleee")
'halo there this is an example'
```

But note that Dan's solution is 4x faster then regex!!