# Getting a "for" loop to remove characters from list if they are equal

Tags: python, loops

In my program, the user inputs a secret word that another person is to guess (hangman). The letters are then put into a list. I am trying to make a loop that checks if there are several equal letters in the list, and remove them if there is.
This I have managed. The problem is that this loop also removes other characters that are not ment to be removed.

```
word = []

for i in range(int(len(secret_word)) - 1):
    if word[l] == word[q]:
        word.pop(l)
        q += 1
        if q > int(len(word)):
            break
    else:
        l +=1
```

Using the word "secret" and then printing the list, the output I get is

```
['s', 'c', 'e', 't']
```

It has removed the e, but unfortunately the r is also removed.
Also, this loop doesn't remove a third equal letter. Using "secretive" the output is

```
['s', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'e']
```

Here, removing one of the e's, but also r, t and v

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: this is python.

Comment: @vault Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to add the programming language as a tag for your post, so that you may receive directed answers.

Comment: You should add that to your tag list then.

Comment: but I can not edit the post after posting, can I?

Comment: @vault of course you can, there's an [edit] button underneath it

Comment: And since this is now tagged as Python, what's wrong with just `set(word)` (or `list(set(word))` if you really need a list)?

Comment: You're not referencing `i` in the loop?

Comment: @UnholySheep i'm not familiar with this statement, pass a link please?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Removing duplicate characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841303/removing-duplicate-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: One piece of advise: if you want to remove items from whatever collection, always start at the end and move backwards to the first entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code is missing a number of features such as the initialization of `q` and `l`. And I suspect you must have an outer loop that you're not showing us, otherwise the example doesn't make a lot of sense (in the example as given `word` is just an empty list).

If you want all the unique letters in a string you can do so easily with `set()`:

```
unique_letters = set(secret_word)
```

However, that will not preserve order. I don't know for your case if you even need to preserve order. But if you wanted to there are many ways to do so, often still involving `set()` but not necessarily. Here's one way:

```
unique_letters = []
seen = set()
for let in secret_word:
    if let in seen:
        continue

    unique_letters.append(let)
    seen.add(let)
```

Another way, as a one-liner, might be something like:

```
unique_letters = sorted(set(secret_word), key=secret_word.index)
```

Those are just a few examples. There are many ways to do this. I'm sorry I can't say exactly what's wrong with you code. The example is missing too much context. But you're *probably* overcomplicating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
word = 'secretblahblahset'
result = ''

for c in word:
  if not c in result:
    result += c 

print(result)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the (implied) question as to why OP's code doesn't work

Comment: it doesn't work because he's iterating over an array while it's being modified

Comment: Your answer should include that then.  Btw, I didn't mark you down.