# How to perform in-place removal of duplicates from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, duplicates, conditional-statements, index-error

I am trying to implement an inplace algorithm to remove duplicates from a string in Python.

```
str1 = "geeksforgeeks"
for i in range(len(str1)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(str1)-1):
         if str1[i] == str1[j]:  //Error Line
                      str1 = str1[0:j]+""+str1[j+1:]



print str1
```

In the above code, I am trying to replace the duplicate character with whitespace. But I get `IndexError: string index out of range` at `if str1[i] == str1[j]`. Am I missing out on something or is it not the right way?

My expected output is: `geksfor`

Comment: `i` takes on the value of all valid indices of `str1`. Then `j` is `i+1`. When `i` is the highest valid index, `j` is thus out of range.

Comment: What is expected value?

Comment: @Alderven When i is 0 and j is 10, I get IndexError

Comment: @Alderven Expected output is: geksfor

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 when i is 10, j is 10 and length of string is 10, j<len(str)-1 should work right?

Comment: You're altering the length of the string while going through it, therefore the range changes.

Comment: You cannot perform in-place modification of a string in Python. Strings are immutable.

Comment: @Jab I am trying to do inplace, hence I can't use another array.

Comment: @AdamSmith But this was a contest question.

Comment: @Animeartistfromhell7 then the contest is nonsensical. You can't modify strings in-place in Python. Full stop.

Comment: @AdamSmith Then I should try another language? like C?

Comment: @Animeartistfromhell7 I have no experience in C, so I couldn't tell you, but you *cannot* do this in Python. It breaks the language specification (strings are immutable)

Comment: @Animeartistfromhell7 You can use a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray), which is mutable.

Comment: "when i is 10, j is 10" Why would that be the case when the inner loop for which `j` is the loop variable uses a `range` object that starts with `i+1`?

Comment: @Keith only if he only uses ascii strings. Python strings are unicode since Python3.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of this with just a set and a comprehension. No need to complicate things.

```
str1 = "geeksforgeeks"

seen = set()
seen_add = seen.add
print(''.join(s for s in str1 if not (s in seen or seen_add(s))))
#geksfor
```

> "Simple is better than complex."
>
> <sup>~ See [PEP20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)</sup>

**Edit**

While the above is more simple than your answer, it is the most performant way of [removing duplicates from a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/480227/225020) the more simple solution would be to use:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
print("".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(str1)))
```

Comment: That's an interesting (non-obvious) use of the `or` conditional. Which is to say "Thanks! I hate it!"

Comment: I'm sorry? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: There are simplest solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841303/removing-duplicate-characters-from-a-string

Comment: Well, while keeping with simplicity and performance I say [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order) is what I prefer. And I'm saying simplicity in comparison to OP's solution.

Comment: @AdamSmith - It's lifted from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/480227/2617068), the citation for which was eventually added in the [fourth revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54965808/4).

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to modify strings in-place in Python, the same way that it's impossible to modify *numbers* in-place in Python.

```
a = "something"
b = 3

b += 1        # allocates a new integer, 4, and assigns it to b
a += " else"  # allocates a new string, " else", concatenates it to `a` to produce "something else"
              # then assigns it to a
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed `str` is immutable, so *in-place* requirement make no sense.
If you want to get desired output I would do it following way:

```
str1 = 'geeksforgeeks'
out = ''.join([i for inx,i in enumerate(str1) if str1.index(i)==inx])
print(out) #prints: geksfor
```

Here I used `enumerate` function to get numerated (`inx`) letters and fact that `.index` method of `str`, returns lowest possible index of element therefore `str1.index('e')` for given string is `1`, not `2`, not `9` and not `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of `unique_everseen` from [`itertools recipes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def unique_everseen(iterable)
    seen = set()
    see _ add = seen.add
    for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
        seen_add(element)
        yield element
```

You can then use this generator with `str.join` to get the expected output.

```
str1 = "geeksforgeeks"
new_str1 = ''.join(unique_everseen(str1)) # 'geksfor'
```