# write a program in python which does not contain any repeating character from input string . example: A is repeated of a

Tags: python, python-3.x

input is: `This is An Example`

Output: `This An Exmpl`

```
li = input("Enter your Sting")
res = ''
for ch in li:
    if ch not in res :
        res = res + ch
        print(res, end=' ')
```

Comment: Whats the question? how come you can have multiple space chars? space char is repeated several times in the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicate characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841303/removing-duplicate-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

```
li = input("Enter your string")
res = ''
for ch in li.lower():
    if ch not in res:
        res = res + ch
print(res.title(), end='')
```

Comment: This doesnt produce the output the OP is trying to get

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there will be a more elegant way to do this but for now here is a working version which you could refactor or reduce if needed

```py
user_input = input("sentance: ")
seen = set()
filtered_words = []
for word in user_input.split():
    filtered_word = ""
    for char in word:
        if char.lower() in seen:
            continue
        filtered_word += char
        seen.add(char.lower())
    if filtered_word != "":
        filtered_words.append(filtered_word)
print(*filtered_words)
```