# Removing duplicates in each item in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list which contains the below values.

```
list1= ['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA']
```

How should I remove duplicates in each item in a list such that i get the following output

```
list1= ['AB', 'CA', 'AD']
```

The order should be preserved here

Comment: Can you [edit] the question, showing what you have tried, that didn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicate characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841303/removing-duplicate-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set` combined with list comprehension if you don't want the letter ordering to be preserved:

```
list1= ['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA']
list1 = [''.join(set(l)) for l in list1]
print(list1)
```

Or use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want the ordering to be preserved:

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
list1= ['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA']
list1 = [''.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(l).keys()) for l in list1]
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dict using characters on the strings as keys to eliminate duplicates.

```
list1= ['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA']
list1 = [''.join(dict.fromkeys(l).keys()) for l in list1]
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the list, cast to set, join

```
new_list = []
for word in list1:
    new_list.append(''.join(set(word)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution for fun:

```
>>> import re
>>> [re.sub(r'(.)(?=.*\1)', '', s[::-1])[::-1] for s in list1]
['AB', 'CA', 'AD']
```

You can omit the reversals if you're ok with keeping the *last* occurrence of each:

```
>>> [re.sub(r'(.)(?=.*\1)', '', s) for s in list1]
['AB', 'CA', 'DA']
```

Proper solution would be:

```
>>> [''.join(dict.fromkeys(s)) for s in list1]
['AB', 'CA', 'AD']
```

(Not sure why the others use `.keys()`, that just unnecessarily costs extra code, time and space.)